I want to simulate a material with 3 atom types in LAMMPS, but the LJ parameters aren't available in any source. How can I calculate them?
I am trying to find the thermal conductivity of a material with 3 atoms kinds through the Green-Kubo method. I could find the LJ pair coefficients of the material in any literature or database. I tried to estimate the values with Lorentz-Berthelot mixing rules but the obtained thermal conductivity with those parameters is much less than the experimental values.
How can I parameterize the interatomic potential such as LJ for my system?
